# Should we check id in POST action edit or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see everywhere (in each tutorial) something like that:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
    if (employee == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(employee);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

So in GET action edit we check if id exists but in POST action edit not. Shouldn't we check also id in POST action edit? I mean something like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    // Check if employe exists in database:
    Employee employeeFromDB = db.Employees.Find(employee.id);
    if (employeeFromDB == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

Or maybe this isn't necessary because database doesn't allow to save employee with bad id? What do you think?

Comment: You should probably return HTTP 400 Bad Request if an invalid id was sent.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Now you're getting into Holy War territory. ;-) There are lots of different opinions on what should be returned in such a case. I tend to prefer `404` myself, but others prefer to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not necessary, for the reason you note; Your code is going to result in an `UPDATE` command, but if the id of the entity is not valid, you'll get an error. There's no need to explicitly load it again, *for purposes of checking the existence of an entity matching the id*...

That said, there are possibly other reasons you want to do that. For instance, to make sure the logged-on user is allowed to edit that particular entity.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would address earlier rather than later is decoupling your entity model from your view, this is not good practice.  What if your entities contain sensitive data? or complex models? This data is viewable in the browser.  You potentially end up passing additional data to your view and end up with 'fat' models, keep them small and necessary.

With a View Model you can apply validations to them which will handle your problem for you. These errors will then populate when you call ModelState.IsValid and pass them back to the view.  I use Fluent Validation instead of the default MVC annotations out of preference.  But check out both / similar and see which suits you.

By separating out your validations into your view model you keep your controllers nice and tidy.  It's more effort of course as you need to map them back and forth from your database, but it gives you a great deal of flexibility whereby you can extend them, add validations etc.

Comment: Model validation is important, but doesn't answer the question whether you should verify that the ID of a POSTed model actually exists in the database (and whether it's accessible for the user POSTing it).

Comment: True, but I think the actual answer is a preference like Andrew Barber points out.  Personally I like to attempt to retrieve the entity first using the ID and if it's not found return this info to the user rather than the alternatives.

Comment: I do agree with the advice here, by the way. In all but the most extremely simple cases, I use View Models, and not the entities directly. (and even in those cases, there must be protection for things like over-posting)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with doing a sanity check imho. If nothing to give you some error during the development phase.

Comment: Not sure how that check helps 'give you some error during the development phase'... Trying to do that without the check will still result in an error if the id in the entity does not exist in the database.